Sharepoint/Project RestApi 0x8102006d Error via postman
My colleagues asked to figure out how to use rest api in Sharepoint (Project) on premise (not online! not sharepoint.com!).
Get requests work fine with NTLM auth via Postman.
Troubles started when i tried any POST, PUT requests.
I figured out that i need to put the X-RequestDigest header which I had got via a POST request to {{ProjectServerUrl}}/_api/contextinfo.
Now when I try POST, PUT, DELETE requests with X-RequestDigest header i get this error:

The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.<nativehr>0x8102006d</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

I rummaged all StackOverflow to find any solutions. No results.

It was mistake in my url. For Sharepoint we MUST use <baseUrl>/_api/contextinfo to get RequestDigest But for Project different url - <baseUrl>/pwa/_api/contextinfo
